# Grab powershell variable from .bat file in same directory

Tags: powershell, batch-file, variables, split

I am a complete newb with bash and powershell scripting and have been trying to figure out how to define a variable in powershell with a variable defined in a batch script stored within the same directory as the powershell script.

Basically, I want to get the Dropbox Path from config.bat and set variable $dropbox for use in other variables within the powershell script. This is what I have so far....

**config.bat:**

```
@Echo OFF
set Dropbox_Path=C:\Users\User\Documents\Dropbox
```

**Extract of test.ps1:**

```
#Grab Dropbox Path from config.bat and set $dropbox variable

$dropbox = Get-Content C:\Users\User\Documents\Dropbox\test\Batch-Files\config.bat `
          | ? { $_ -match "Dropbox_Path=\s*"} `
          | select -First 1 `
          | % { ($_ -split "=", 2)[1] }

# Set other Variables using $dropbox 

$input_csv = "$dropbox\test\Test.csv"
$master_csv = "$dropbox\test\Test-MASTER.csv"
$output_file = "$dropbox\test\Test.txt"
```

Everything works fine if I specify the absolute path for the config.bat file (as shown) but if I try using relative paths `$PSScriptRoot\config.bat` or `.\config.bat`, I get errors and powerhsell cannot find the config.bat file showing error...

> "Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\config.bat' because it does not
>   exist."

I have also tried an alternative way and used write-host to see if the variables show the correct directories....

```
$configFullPath = "$($pwd)\config.bat"
Write-Host "Config file full path = $configFullPath"

Import-Module -Force $configFullPath

$dropbox = Get-Content _config.bat `
          | ? { $_ -match "Dropbox_Path=\s*"} `
          | select -First 1 `
          | % { ($_ -split "=", 2)[1] }

Write-Host "Config file full path = $configFullPath"
Write-Host "Dropbox Path = $dropbox"
PAUSE
```

With the above code, I get this PS error....

> "Import-Module : The specified module 'C:\Users\User\config.bat' was
>   not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
>   directory."

The output shows:

```
Config file full path = C:\Users\User\config.bat    # WRONG
Dropbox Path =
```

The path needs to be relative for my purposes and its probably something embarrassingly super simple that the coding gurus here will make me look like a complete numpty :)

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn to the MyInvocation object to find the path to the script.

```
$this_dir = [io.path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
$this_dir

$dropbox = Get-Content -Path "$([io.path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path))\config.bat" `
          | ? { $_ -match "Dropbox_Path=\s*"} `
          | select -First 1 `
          | % { ($_ -split "=", 2)[1] }

$dropbox
```

**Update:** Based on subsequent answers, particularly mklement0, here is a revised answer.

For all versions of PowerShell:

```
$scriptdir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent
$dropbox = (Select-String -List `
    -Pattern ' Dropbox_Path=(.*)' `
    -Path "$scriptdir/config.bat").Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```

For PowerShell 3.0+ versions:

```
$dropbox = (Select-String -List `
    -Pattern ' Dropbox_Path=(.*)' `
    -Path $PSScriptRoot/config.bat).Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: I now get this error using MyInvocation..... "Exception calling "GetDirectoryName" with "1" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form."
At line:1 char:1
+ $dropbox = Get-Content  -Path "$([io.path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCom ...

Comment: "Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\config.bat' because it does not exist."         It just dont seem to define the correct directory for the config file location even though it is in the same directory

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? This works on PowerShell 5 and 6 beta 3.

Comment: I revised the answer to get the current code directory first. What does that give you?

Comment: Powershell Version 4
This error....Exception calling "GetDirectoryName" with "1" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form."

Comment: What does `$this_dir` contain from the revised answer?

Comment: PS C:\Users\User> $this_dir = [io.path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
Exception calling "GetDirectoryName" with "1" argument(s): "The path is not of a legal form."
At line:1 char:1
+ $this_dir = [io.path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

PS C:\Users\User> $this_dir
PS C:\Users\User>

Comment: Got it working now. It was my error, all relative path solutions work perfectly. Embarrassingly, I was copying the code from notepad to powershell rather than running the script from the folder! Doh!!!   Thanks @lit for your help :)

Comment: Glad you got it working. Yes, $MyInvocation is a script-based variable not in the console.

Answer (score 1):

To refer to **the running script's location (directory)**:

- **PSv3+**: Use **`$PSScriptRoot`** (`$PSCommandPath` refers to the script's full filename).
- **PSv2-, except in modules**: Use **`Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`** (`$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` refers to the script's full filename).

An idiomatic PSv3+ reformulation of the code in the question:

```
$dropbox = (Select-String -List ' Dropbox_Path=(.*)' $PSScriptRoot/config.bat).
             Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works as intended:

```
#Grab Dropbox Path from config.bat and set $dropbox variable

$dropbox = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\config.bat `
      | ? { $_ -match "Dropbox_Path="} `
      | select -First 1 `
      | % { ($_ -split "=", 2)[1] }

# Set other Variables using $dropbox 

$input_csv = "$dropbox\test\Test.csv"
$master_csv = "$dropbox\test\Test-MASTER.csv"
$output_file = "$dropbox\test\Test.txt"
```